# Coloring all the variables with the same name with the same color

Tags: color, syntax, variable

I would like to know if there is a possibility to automatically color the variables with the same name with the same color. For example, like in the picture below:

[image]

Right now I need to do it manually one by one, which is very tedious. But I would like to color ALL the variables with the same name.

Comment: It is not quite clear. Do you want that the output is colored? Alternatively, you may want that the input appears colored just during the process of typing. So, what is your aim?

Comment: I want input text to be colored so the code is easier to read. I do not care about the output

Comment: In this case, I do not know the answer. Maybe, there is the possibility to introduce a color the way we introduce the bold or italic fonts (Ctrl+B and Ctrl+I) if somebody knows how to introduce the corresponding hotkeys. I do not know that.

Comment: Andris, I anticipate this can be done a number of ways, so can you, please, answer this question: Should the variable/symbol color change occur immediately upon typing the complete symbol name, or should the change occur after the cell has been evaluated (whether there is output or not should not be of concern here)?

Comment: I would favor that the color changes immediately without evaluating the cell, but if it makes the problem difficult, other option is fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try some of these for formatting strategies

## For indexed variables

```
x/:Format[x[n_]]=Style[Subscript[x,n],Red];
```

## Colour

```
var1/: Format[var1]:=Style["Var1",{Blue,Bold}]
var2/: Format[var2]:=Style["Var2",{Purple,Bold}]
var3/: Format[var3]:=Style["Var1",{Red,Bold}]
```

## Change variable display

```
Format[r[t_]]=\[Rho][t];
Format[r[n_][t_]]=Subscript[Stype[\[Rho],Orange],Stype[n,Green]][t];
```

## Visuals

[image]

Or, particularly what you asked for:

[image]

Comment: @AndrisErglis, does this provide what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, this comes in handy. But I rather wanted my input text to be colored so that my dense code is easier to read.