# Using subscripted variables in the LaTeX output

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, notebooks, output, latex

When I run the following code in Mathematica:

```
  mat = {{x1,x2,x3,x6,x7,x8,x11,x12},{x3,x1,x2,x8,x6,x7,x11,x12},{x3,x2,x1,x8,x7,x6,x12,x11},{x2,x3,x1,x7,x8,x6,x11,x12},{x1,x3,x2,x6,x8,x7,x12,x11},{x2,x1,x3,x7,x6,x8,x12,x11},{x4,x4,x4,x9,x9,x9,x13,x13},{x5,x5,x5,x10,x10,x10,x14,x14}}

  res = Det[mat];

  Factor[res]
```

I get the following output.

$$-9 (x11-x12) (x2 x6-x3 x6-x1 x7+x3 x7+x1 x8-x2 x8)^2 (-2 x1 x10 x13-2 x10 x13 x2-2 x10 x13 x3+3 x10 x11 x4+3 x10 x12 x4-2 x14 x4 x6+2 x13 x5 x6-2 x14 x4 x7+2 x13 x5 x7-2 x14 x4 x8+2 x13 x5 x8+2 x1 x14 x9+2 x14 x2 x9+2 x14 x3 x9-3 x11 x5 x9-3 x12 x5 x9)$$

Formatted as $\LaTeX$, the output is:

-9 (\text{x11}-\text{x12}) (-\text{x1} \text{x7}+\text{x1} \text{x8}+\text{x2} \text{x6}-\text{x2} \text{x8}-\text{x3} \text{x6}+\text{x3} \text{x7})^2 ...

**Question**

Is there any way to get the $\LaTeX$ output to be formatted as subscripted variables instead?

-9 (x_{11}-x_{12}) (-x_1 x_7+x_1 x_8+x_2 x_6-x_2 x_8-x_3 x_6+x_3 x_7)^2...

I could not get [*TeXForm*](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html) to work either.

Comment: Does `TeXForm` do what you have in mind?

Comment: @Syed: I did not think to give that a try - but will do so now. Nope, it returns -9 (\text{x11}-\text{x12}) (-\text{x1} \text{x7}+\text{x1} \text{x8}+\text{x2}
   \text{x6}-\text{x2} \text{x8}-\text{x3} \text{x6}+\text{x3} \text{x7})^2

Comment: Could you please load the actual Mma expression? Thanks.

Comment: @Syed: Added, thanks

Comment: how does Mathematica supposed to know you want   `x1` output in latex to be `x_1`?  how about if the input is  `xn` is this supposed to come out in latex as `x_n` also? The Latex conversion now is the correct translation.

Comment: @Nasser: Why can't there be some sort of option for subscripted variables? After all, TexForm shows an example of that.

Comment: But your input `x1` is _not_ subscripted variable. Here is a screen shot   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAzHw.png)   if you had you variable as subscripted then the latex would have come out as you wanted.

Comment: @Nasser: I am asking generally because this is a recurring thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to automatically put the part of a variable name after the first letter in symbolized subscripts?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30849/how-to-automatically-put-the-part-of-a-variable-name-after-the-first-letter-in-s)

Comment: @xzczd: I don't see how, as I am not asking about subscripted display variables, but LaTex output.

Comment: Well, once you have it displayed properly, you can transform it to $\LaTeX$ code, can't you? Just `Factor[res] // subscriptForm` then right click, Copy As -> LaTeX.

Comment: I've built a function for this problem, but can't post an answer anymore. @Moo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible workaround.

```
alist = ToExpression["x" <> ToString[#] & /@ Range[15]]
blist = Table[Subscript[x, i], {i, 1, 15}]
rules = Thread[Rule[alist, blist]]
```

$$\left\{\text{x1}\to x_1,\text{x2}\to x_2,\text{x3}\to x_3,\text{x4}\to x_4,\text{x5}\to x_5,\text{x6}\to x_6,\text{x7}\to x_7,\text{x8}\to x_8,\text{x9}\to x_9,\text{x10}\to x_{10},\text{x11}\to x_{11},\text{x12}\to x_{12},\text{x13}\to x_{13},\text{x14}\to x_{14},\text{x15}\to x_{15}\right\}$$

---

```
mat = {{x1, x2, x3, x6, x7, x8, x11, x12}, {x3, x1, x2, x8, x6, x7, 
   x11, x12}, {x3, x2, x1, x8, x7, x6, x12, x11}, {x2, x3, x1, x7, x8,
    x6, x11, x12}, {x1, x3, x2, x6, x8, x7, x12, x11}, {x2, x1, x3, 
   x7, x6, x8, x12, x11}, {x4, x4, x4, x9, x9, x9, x13, x13}, {x5, x5,
    x5, x10, x10, x10, x14, x14}}
res = Det[mat];
expr = Factor[res]
expr /. rules // TeXForm
```

(*

-9 \left(x_2 x_6-x_3 x_6-x_1 x_7+x_3 x_7+x_1 x_8-x_2
x_8\right){}^2 \left(x_{11}-x_{12}\right) \left(-3 x_5
x_9 x_{11}+3 x_4 x_{10} x_{11}-3 x_5 x_9 x_{12}+3 x_4
x_{10} x_{12}+2 x_5 x_6 x_{13}+2 x_5 x_7 x_{13}+2 x_5
x_8 x_{13}-2 x_1 x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_2 x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_3
x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_4 x_6 x_{14}-2 x_4 x_7 x_{14}-2 x_4
x_8 x_{14}+2 x_1 x_9 x_{14}+2 x_2 x_9 x_{14}+2 x_3 x_9
x_{14}\right)

*)

As LateX:

$$-9 \left(x_2 x_6-x_3 x_6-x_1 x_7+x_3 x_7+x_1 x_8-x_2
   x_8\right){}^2 \left(x_{11}-x_{12}\right) \left(-3 x_5
   x_9 x_{11}+3 x_4 x_{10} x_{11}-3 x_5 x_9 x_{12}+3 x_4
   x_{10} x_{12}+2 x_5 x_6 x_{13}+2 x_5 x_7 x_{13}+2 x_5
   x_8 x_{13}-2 x_1 x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_2 x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_3
   x_{10} x_{13}-2 x_4 x_6 x_{14}-2 x_4 x_7 x_{14}-2 x_4
   x_8 x_{14}+2 x_1 x_9 x_{14}+2 x_2 x_9 x_{14}+2 x_3 x_9
   x_{14}\right)$$

Comment: I am surprised there is not an option for subscripted variables. Thanks!

Comment: @Moo You can have [indexed variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94294/10397), and [format their display however you like](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/256172/10397).  It is just a very bad idea to use `Subscript` for variables.

Comment: @rhermans: Understood, I only care about for the output as the text count is limited and having all those text items wastes a lot of space. As you can see, I did not use subscripted variables in the problem statement as I know that causes grief. Thanks.

Comment: @Moo You can use `ResourceFunction["SymbolToSubscript"][expr]`.

Comment: @E.Chan-López: Thanks - I will that a go.